# How to Describe a Scene from Video?

Tags: fantasy, description, scene, young-adult

I'm new to English (three years) and I want help describing this video for my fantasy novel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymcen0EjmiU.

I don't want you to do it at my place, but I really want to see how *you* would describe it (especially after 0:32). I have difficulties describing actions and voices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your response, time, and consideration!

Edit: Thank you for your help, I already described this scene and it turned out to be really good.

Comment: If one of the answers here gave you what you needed, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons.  If you figured it out on your own, it would be best if you were to add an answer explaining what you did, since the answers here are for the whole Internet and not just for the person asking the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't try to describe it, but here's how I would go about it:

Put myself deep inside Brave's viewpoint. Notice what details she is taking in through her senses (see, hear, smell, touch, taste). Especially focus on her opinions of those sensory details. Whatever she has an opinion about, write that. Stay with her senses and opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Dale brings up a good point; for the most part, motion pictures are primarily told from the third person perspective.  It's not better or worse, simply a constraint of the medium.  Generally speaking, a motion picture story is what the audience can objectively see.  By contrast, novels aren't constrained by perspective and can also include what the character is subjectively feeling in the first person as well.

When people talk about the differences between books and film adaptations, this is one of the biggest.